# Starting ffserver on macos - Permission Denied

Tags: mac-osx, video-streaming, ffmpeg

I am trying to start ffserver on Snow leopard.

```
dev:~ Shashank$ ffserver -d -f /usr/etc/ffserver.config
```

I get this in my terminal.

```
ffserver version 1.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb 27 2013 00:48:40 with gcc 4.2.1 (GCC) (Apple Inc. build 5664)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --host-cflags='-Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6' --host-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
bind(port 100): Permission denied
Wed Feb 27 23:08:46 2013 Could not start server
```

This is my config file.

```
Port 100
BindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 50000
NoDaemon
<Feed webcam.ffm>
file /tmp/webcam.ffm
FileMaxSize 10M
</Feed>

<Stream webcam.mjpeg>
Feed webcam.ffm
Format mjpeg
VideoSize 640x480
VideoFrameRate 10
VideoBitRate 2000
VideoQMin 1
VideoQMax 10
</Stream>
```

Where am I going wrong? Do i need to provide more information? 
Thankyou..

Comment: Can you explain to us how this question is related to *professional system administration* as described in the [FAQ]?  If you're trying to do this on a home machine to make a media server for yourself you might be better served on one of http://superuser.com, [apple.se], or [unix.se]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told the server to bind to port 100.

On UNIX systems such as Mac OS X and Linux, ports below 1024 can only be listened to by the root user.

To resolve the issue, use one of the following two solutions:

1. Select a different port for the server, which is 1024 or higher.
2. Run the server as the root user, e.g. with `sudo`. (Not recommended)

Comment: THe first solution worked. Thankyou.

I tried sudo before I asked the question.. didnt work..

dev:~ Shashank$ sudo ffserver -d -f /usr/etc/ffserver.config
sudo: must be setuid root

Comment: Sudo might be disabled on your system, preventing you from using that option.